# How to use list each element as repeating times to be used as index later

Tags: python

I have a map_list of nested dict and list combinations, `len(map_list)=9`, Each element has repeating block structure, I also manage to get a `count_list=[1, 6, 26, 5, 4, 1, 10, 7, 9]` which represents the counting number of those repeating structures.

How can I use the map list length and element of count list to represent as indexes if I want to get some data out when dipping deeper of the map_list?

I have tried the iteration tools repeat and transitional 2 for loops, but didn’t succeed, any help would be appreciated a lot for a newbies.

My expect result is: i, c

```
0 0,
1 0,
1 1,
1,2,
1,3,
1,4
1,5
2,0
2,1
...
2,25
3,0
3,1,
...
8,8
```

Because I want to use those as index later.my problem is when trying to repeat on the element of count list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to get the index and value of each element of a list.

```
count_list = [1, 6, 26, 5, 4, 1, 10, 7, 9]

for i, c in enumerate(count_list):
    for j in range(c):
        print((i, j))
```

Comment: Edited to define `count_list`.